# Embed videos from Youtube, Vimeo, etc

Tags: html, video, youtube

I want to embed videos on my site, but I don't want to keep videos on my server. I want something like an iframe, but I want to be capable to use links from any source, not just from youtube or vimeo. What can I do?

```
  <iframe width="560" height="349" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FM7MFYoylVs?enablejsapi=1&playsinline=1&controls=0" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>
```

Here is what i've tried but that's not what I need.:(

Answer (score 0):

I think `iframe` should be your best choice, But as `iframe` is not what you need , you can also have a look at `object`

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W7qWa52k-nE"
   width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <object data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W7qWa52k-nE"
   width="560" height="315"></object>

<object data="http://player.vimeo.com/video/214414572"     
width="561" height="316" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen 
allowFullScreen></object>
 </body>
</html>
```

support to vimeo videos depents on the target as vimeo videos are flash. so if you display a vimeo video using `iframe` or `object` then as long as device is supported, it will show the video

Comment: i have addeed a vimeo example ... have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have your own iframe and then embed the required iframe or src as required.
So you would have a MASTER iframe that when loaded will hold the youtube iframe inside. And you can do the same with each option that you are requiring. Just set your iframe size to match the others.